# Control theory - overshoot max

Tags: electrical-engineering

So, during my last class the teacher asked if we could go from:

MO = e(-π*ξ / √1-ξ²) to ξ= (-ln*(MO)) / (√π²+ln²(MO))

MO = Max overshoot
ξ = zeta
e = exp

Does anyone understand what he meant by that? Did I just misunderstand?
Tried a few times but I just can't make sense of how to go from the MO equation to the zeta one.

Comment: Does $e(\dots)$ mean $exp(\dots)$ ? If so, it appears to be just a re arrangement of the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be good to see what you tried and I'm sure your teacher would too, but does this make it any clearer?

$$
MO = e^{-\pi \frac{\zeta}{\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}}}
$$
$$
ln(MO) = -\pi\frac{\zeta}{\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}}
$$

$$
ln(MO)^2 = (ln(MO)^2 +\pi^2)\zeta^2
$$

$$
 \zeta^2 = \frac{ln(MO)^2}{ln(MO)^2 +\pi^2}
$$

Comment: Ty, turns out it was just algebra, haha!